# Nginx ReWrite location to New API endpoints

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to move old API endpoints to new Restful (descriptive) endpoints. I have tried the below nginx configuration for rewriting old requests to the new endpoints but it is not working. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        root /path/to/api/entry/file;

        index index.php;

        server_name api.example.com;

    #Below not rewriting http://api.example.com/create/ to http://api.example.com/users/v1/create
    rewrite ^/create/ /users/v1/create last; 

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;

                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                access_log /var/log/nginx/example_api-access.log;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/example_api-error.log;

                fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        }

}
```

An example to what am trying to achieve is rewrite http://api.example.com/create/ to http://api.example.com/users/v1/create and forward the request to the entry script (index.php) which will bootstrap the necessary controller to handle the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rewrite...last` doesn't achieve anything, as it's an internal process which eventually ends at `/index.php`. Your `index.php` script uses the original request (probably from the REQUEST_URI parameter) to determine the API endpoint.

You need to perform an external redirection using `rewrite...permanent` to make it visible to `index.php`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/create/ /users/v1/create permanent;
```

Or more efficiently, and to work with POST and GET requests:

```
location /create/ { return 307 /users/v1/create$is_args$args; }
```

---

If you want to support the old API without a redirection, you will need to fool `index.php` with a dedicated location block, for example:

```
location /create/ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI     /users/v1/create;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Many of your `fastcgi` directives can be moved into the outer block, so that you do not need to write them twice. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html) for details.

Comment: The last example did it for me.
Both Endpoints are working thanks